# Continuous bijective functions of Real numbers are open maps

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am trying to prove that continuous bijective functions from  real numbers to Real numbers take open sets to open sets. I think this is true. Inverse of continuous bijective function is again continuous and pre image of open sets under function are open sets.  This is my approach. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct (and the statement is true).

Comment: I think for a complete solution you should prove that the inverse of a continuous bijection $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. It's worth noting that any such $f$ is monotone.

Comment: Your "approach" is just a  reformulation of the problem. Why should the inverse of a continuous bijective map be  continuous ?

Comment: Can I say that a continuous bijection on reals will be continuous on compact set $[-n,n]$, and hence it's inverse will also be continuous using compactness, and let $n$ go to Infinity.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, but there are some details to be added. The best approach is through monotonicity of the function, as commented by @carmichael561 .